# ng-repeat: How to access to the field name

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to use a nested `ng-repeat` and within the second one I need to filter according a `ng-model` that I set before. But within the second `ng-repeat` I need to place a `ng-if` that depends on the field name.

The thing is that I've tried to use the (key, value) form (which works perfectly) but then it's very annoying to apply a filter. So I was wondering if there is a way to access to the name field.

For example:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item2 in items2">
    <td ng-repeat="val in item2 | filer:blabla" ng-if="val.field != 'foto'">{{val}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, this filter code should not be sitting in your view (html file) but in your controller as a function evaluated by ng-show /ng-if function.= which will be called from your view.

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually have a function evaluate the result, and using `Object.keys` you can get the name of the field and compare it.

Since angular will loop through the values of your object, you would need the index of `ng-repeat` to get the actual field.

In the html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item2 in items2">
    <td ng-repeat="val in item2 | filer:blabla" 
        ng-if="shouldBeVisible(item2, $index, 'foto')">{{val}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.shouldBeVisible = (item, $index, prop)=>{
    return Object.keys(item)[$index] !== prop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index to access the val.field

Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabs00/05kqs5wm/1/)

html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item[0].field}} <!-- just a sanity check -->
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="val in item" ng-if="item[$index].field !== 'apple'">{{val.value}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
      [
      {
        field: 'apple',
        value: 'pie'
      },
      {
        field: 'chocolate',
        value: 'cake'
      }
      ]
    ];
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for the anwsers, I solved it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item2 in items2">
    <td ng-repeat="ite in item2" >
        <img width="50px" ng-if="$index == 0" ng-src="{{ite}}" lazy-src/>
        <span ng-if="$index != 0">{{ite}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Since I getting the data from a DB dinámically on this way:

```
app.controller("getItems2", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
var gi2 = this;
$rootScope.$on("itemClicked",function(event,id){
    console.log(id);
    gi2.getItems(id);
});

this.getItems = function(idClase){
    $http.get('main/getItems2?idClase='+idClase).
    then(function (response) {
        $scope.columns = [];
        response.data.forEach(function(e){
            e.Foto = "img/"+e.Foto;
        });
        $scope.items2 = response.data;
        console.log($scope.items2);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // log error
    });
};
this.getItems(1);
});
```